# C++ heap corruption on new

Tags: c++, memory, neural-network

I'm writing simple ANN (neural network) for functions' approximation. I got crash with message: "Heap corrupted". I found few advices how to resolve it, but nothing help.
I got error at first line of this function:

```
 void LU(double** A, double** &L, double** &U, int s){
    U = new double*[s];
    L = new double*[s];
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++){
        U[i] = new double[s];
        L[i] = new double[s];
        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
            U[i][j] = A[i][j];
    }
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s; i = ++j){
        L[i][j] = 1;
        for (int k = i + 1; k < s - 1; k++){
            L[k][j] = U[k][j] / U[i][j];
            double* vec_t = mul(U[i], L[k][j], s);
            for (int z = 0; z < s; z++)
                U[k][z] = U[k][z] - vec_t[z];
            delete[] vec_t;
        }
    }
};
```

As I understood from debagger's information: two arrays (U and L) has been passed to function with some addresses in memory. And it's quite strange because I didn't initialize it. I call this function two times and first time it works nicely (ok, at least it works), but at second call it crashes. I have no idea how to resolve it.
There is link to whole project: [CLICK](https://github.com/IljaKosynkin/Aproximation)
I'm working in MS Visual Studio 2013 under Windows 7 x64.

**UPDATE**
According to some commentaries below I should provide some additive information.
First of all, sorry for quality of code. I wrote it only for myself for 2 days.
Second, when I said "at second call", I mean that first I call LU when I need to get determinant of S (I use LU decomposition fot this) and it working without any crashes. Second call it's when I trying to get inverse of matrix (the same, S). And when I call detLU at [0, 0] point of matrix (to get cofactor) I got this crash.
Third, if I get information from debagger correctly, arrays L and U passes in function at second call with already defined memory's addresses. I can't understand why, becouse before LU call I have just wrote "double** L; double** U;" without any initialization.
I can try provide some additional debug information or some tests, if somebody explain me what exactly I have to do.

Comment: Please produce an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: "but at second call it crashes" can mean a lot of things.  Please be specific.

Comment: The heap could have become corrupted at any time, even outside that function or before it was called.

Comment: Do you delete the memory U and L point to after the function.  If not you are going to get a memory leak.

Comment: It's apparently not the code here which causes corruption.  i tried to compile and reun your code, but `TestingSet.txt` is missing.  Can you provide it ?

Comment: Oh, forgot to provide TestingSet, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point you get a heap corruption error/crash is typically just the symptom of an actual heap overflow/underflow or other memory error at some other time/point in the past. This is why heap corruptions can be difficult to track down.

You have a lot of code and all the double-pointers are difficult to track but I did notice one potential issue:

```
double** initInWeights(double f, int h, int w) {
    double** W = new double*[h];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         W[i] = new double[w];
```

The loop will overflow `W[]` if `h` is less than 10. Chances are that somewhere in your code you have a buffer overflow/underflow or are using memory after it is freed. The complexity and design of your code makes it difficult to pinpoint at a glance.

Is there a reason you are using raw double-pointers instead of simply `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`? This would remove all your manual memory management code, making your code shorter, simpler, and more importantly remove the heap corruption issue.

Barring that you should double-check that all manually allocated memory is the correct size and access loops can never go out-of-bounds.

**Update** -- I think your problem may lie with a buffer overflow in the `extract()` function in `matrix.cpp`:

```
double** extract(double** mat, int s, int col, int row)
{
    double** ext = new double*[s - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < s - 1; i++)
    {
        ext[i] = new double[s - 1];
    }

    int ext_c = 0, ext_r = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        if (i != row)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
            {                                        // Overflow on ext_c here
                if (j != col) ext[ext_r][ext_c++] = mat[i][j];   
            }
            ext_r++;
        }
    }

    return ext;
};
```

You never reset `ext_c` so it simply keeps increasing in size up to `(s-1)*(s-1)` which obviously overflows the `ext[]` array. To fix this you simply need to change the inner loop definition to:

```
 for (int j = 0, ext_c = 0; j < s; j++)
```

At least that one change lets me run your project without any heap corruption errors.

Comment: Yes, I got this. It's so simply... and stupid mistake. Thanks a lot! Unfortunately I haven't enough reputation to vote up your answer. Anyway, thank you. Now I will have a lot of headache with test and providing gradient tolerance check, but at least base of project is working.